# LibGDX - Application crashes when call TiledMapRenderer.render()

Tags: java, android, 2d, render, libgdx

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    sprite.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    mLevel.getTiledMapRenderer().getProjectionMatrix().set(camera.combined);
    Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
    tmp.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.unproject(tmp);
    mLevel.getTiledMapRenderer().render(tmp.x, tmp.y, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);

    sprite.begin();
    ...
    sprite.end();
}
```

Here is what I get when launching the desktop version :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 0, must be at least 1. Because at most 1 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 1 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.throwBufferSizeException(BufferChecks.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBufferSize(BufferChecks.java:189)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBuffer(BufferChecks.java:230)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBufferData(GL15.java:141)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGL20.glBufferData(LwjglGL20.java:93)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexBufferObject.bind(VertexBufferObject.java:208)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.bind(Mesh.java:268)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteCache.begin(SpriteCache.java:868)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.tiled.TileMapRenderer.render(TileMapRenderer.java:336)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.tiled.TileMapRenderer.render(TileMapRenderer.java:286)
    at com.crunsh.libgdx.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:102)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:202)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
```

I've tried both [this tuto](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tiles#Render) and [this one](http://dpk.net/2011/05/01/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/#p5), and I get the same error at the same line `mLevel.getTiledMapRenderer().render(tmp.x, tmp.y, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);`.

**EDIT :** I just noticed that the data of my .tmx file was automatically encoded by Tiled Map Editor, so I just desactivated it, but still get the same error.
If I copy/paste [this project](http://dpk.net/2011/05/01/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/#p5) (I mean the whole project, not only the render() method) it works but when I try to load my own map in my own project it just crashes ...

So after that I decided to simplify my `render()` method by just doing like the link I gave before and by using the `TiledMapHelper class` the author provide, so there is my `render()` method now:

```
mHelper.getCamera().update();
mHelper.render();
```

Still crashiiiiiiiiiiiiiingg.....
If someone can please provide some help it would be greatly appreciated because atm i'm really going mad !

Comment: I've seen a similar exception when I have messed up my mesh definitions (either forgetting to load verticies or setting the length to zero).  So, most likely something is incorrect with your tile map definition.  Check to see if there are size/scale requirements (like power of 2 or minimum of X, or something like that) that you are not meeting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked and everything if a power of 2: the viewport of the camera, the size of every tile and the size of my level.png containing all the tiles packed in one image. Only the map size didn't fit, but changing it didn't solve my problem, anyway the tutorial use a map of 60*15 so the map which displays doesn't either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found what caused the error :

1. all the tiles in my "packfile" had -1 as their index
2. all the tiles in my "packfile" had the same name as their original tile file name, but not the same name as the .png file containing all the tiles packed.

Currently my screen is black so I think no tile is draw (probably because I gave random indexes to the tiles in the packfile - **fixed, see the end of the post**) but no exceptions are thrown and that's the point.

Those mistakes are due to the program I used to pack the tiles that was supposed to make me win time lol. So I will try different options or use something else.
If you want to know the program was "TexturePacker GUI" v3.1.0.

If you know what options I should/not use to avoid errors please let me know.

**EDIT :** Found a usefull and working tool for packing tiles, here it is : <s>http://freigabe.philweb.de/bubblr/texturepacker_edited.jar</s>
(link is dead ; use [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69374102/texturepacker-gui-3.1.0.zip) instead. or [another packing tool](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69374102/TilePacker.jar))

To use it open cmd and go to the directory where your downloaded the .jar file and then :

```
//You should create, in the same directory of the .jar file, two additionnal folders
//Call the first folder 'input' and put in all your tiles (rename them "level_1.png", "level_..")
//Call the 2nd folder 'output' and leave it empty
//Then just type in the command prompt : java -jar nameOfDownloadedJarFile.jar input output level
//Then rename the "input1.png" into "level.png", and "level.pack" into "level packfile"
//Open "level packfile" with notepad and change "input1.png" into "level.png"
//Then draw your map using "level.png" in TiledMapEditor
//Then just follow dpk' tutorial for rendering the map and it should work
```

Here is dpk's tutorial I mentioned, just follow from here : http://dpk.net/2011/05/01/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/#p4

If application doesn't crashes but the screen is black, just increase camera's viewport's width & height.

Happy mapping :) !

Comment: I also used the "TexturePacker GUI" and encountered the same problem. Thanks for providing the alternative!

Comment: @tsukimi I uploaded the link by posting a zip of mine. I'm not sure if this is the good one because I have several packers, so let me know if this doesn't work as said in my post.

Comment: @miNde thanks for uploading. This is same as program as i use now. The problem is the way it packs, it packs starting bottom left and going up, where as tiled editor needs the images packed top left going left to right, have you used tiled on your packed file? Now in tiled the indexes from the pack files dont match

Comment: I did only poor tests and yes it worked. But the problem is that since I wrote this post I have been very busy with other stuff so I didn't had the opportunity to use it a lot. Anyway I found another tile packer in my HD, so I can upload it if you want.

Comment: @miNde OK please upload

Comment: @tsukimi I added the link in my answer.

Comment: @miNde thanks again for uploading, i tried the tool , didn't pack how i needed.

Comment: Basically i getting around it by using 2 tilesets which works but i think could hurt performance because of the texture switching.I was going to use a larger width texture 2048 but this is not supported on all phones.