# Build level packfile from map tile for use in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to use tiled for draw my maps. for use this map in libgdx I must build a level packfile, but I can't build it. I use these ways for build it, but all of them has an error in execute...
this is my ways: [Source for this way](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/04/16/LibGDX-Tutorial-11-Tiled-Maps-Part-1-Simple-Orthogonal-Maps.aspx)

```
java -jar TexturePacker.java inputdirectory outputdirectory level
```

for this one, I always get a jar export from TexturePacker class, then open a command window on it (folder of it) then write like it:

```
java -jar TexturePacker.jar c:\MySideScrollGame\data\world\level1 c:\ level.tmx
```

and so on...
and this on: [Source for this way](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps)

```
java -classpath libs/gdx.jar:libs/gdx-tools.jar:libs/gdx-tiled-preprocessor.jar
 com.badlogic.gdx.tiledmappacker.TiledMapPacker
 mygame/maps
 mygame-android/assets/maps
 --strip-unused
```

my way:

```
java -classpath libs\gdx.jar;libs\gdx-tools.jar;libs\gdx-tiled-preprocessor.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tiledmappacker.TiledMapPacker c:\MySideScrollGame\data\packer c:\MySideScrollGame\data\packer
```

but this on is like that too. Error.
so plz, if anyone knows where is my problem or who, that did this before , say it to me. thanks a lot.

EDIT :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" javax.media.opengl.GLException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\packer\input\level_1 packfile (Internal)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:271)
at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(GLCanvas.java:410)
at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:244)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglAnimator.display(JoglAnimator.java:137)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglAnimator$MainLoop.run(JoglAnimator.java:174)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\packer\input\level_1 packfile (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:108)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:99)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.tiled.TileAtlas.<init>(TileAtlas.java:49)
at com.example.jumpertutorial.TiledMapHelper.loadMap(TiledMapHelper.java:111)
at com.example.jumpertutorial.JumperTutorial.create(JumperTutorial.java:78)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglGraphics.init(JoglGraphics.java:87)
at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:72)
at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas$InitAction.run(GLCanvas.java:418)
at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:189)
at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas$DisplayOnEventDispatchThreadAction.run(GLCanvas.java:452)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use `TexturePacker`. I used to use it too, but I think it is bugged as I've never been able to make it work.

I found an other tool to do this, but you have to do a few other things. I suggest you to take a look at [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737426/libgdx-application-crashes-when-call-tiledmaprenderer-render/11747244#11747244) about the same problem as everything is explained.

Comment: look, i did what ever u said. but i still have problem. there is some questions.after build pack file and tmx file, did i must copy them to dpk's folders? or when must i build my map? after build pack or before it? and at last,in dpk's tutorial, u said "Here is dpk's tutorial I mentioned, just follow from here", so u mean i follow it from "Saving the map data to the projects" section?...i try it again, and i hope it work.

Comment: and one another question, if i first build pack file, then build map, did it (i mean map) has effect on pack file?? cuz i just saw pack file before and after building map, and it was same!!! i think pack file must change with different maps...

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear:

```
File not found: data\packer\input\level_1 packfile
```

There isn't a file with that name.

This

```
java -jar TexturePacker.java inputdirectory outputdirectory level
```

makes me think the file is called: **level.pack**