# LibGDX could not parse tmx file: file not found

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I'm attempting to show an isometric tiled map using LibGDX and Eclipse.

However, when running the project i encounter this error(s):

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: E:/Documenti/eclipseiso/desktop/map.tmx
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:78)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
at com.mygdx.eclipseiso.screens.Play.show(Play.java:20)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
at com.mygdx.eclipseiso.eclipseiso.create(eclipseiso.java:12)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: E:\Documenti\eclipseiso\desktop\map.tmx (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
    ... 7 more

The code is as follows:

```
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map.tmx");
renderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map);
```

and the file named "map.tmx" is located inside assets/maps.

Thus the actual path is:

```
assets/maps/map.tmx
```

The map is **not** compressed as xml, it's compressed as gzip.

Here's the content of the map.tmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="isometric" renderorder="right-down" width="5" height="5" tilewidth="100" tileheight="50" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="joj" tilewidth="100" tileheight="350">
  <tile id="0">
   <image width="100" height="350" source="one.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
   <image width="100" height="350" source="two.png"/>
  </tile>
  <tile id="2">
   <image width="100" height="350" source="three.png"/>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Livello tile 1" width="5" height="5">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJxjZmBgYAZiRiTMjCTGBMXMaBibGC4MAAxQAEE=
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Also, i've created the maps folder through Eclipse by right clicking the assets folder and adding a new package named maps, then i moved the required files into the maps folder, always through Eclipse.

The maps folder wasn't generated inside assets (at least graphically), so i moved it inside the assets folder, but regardless of that the program would not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it sorted out:

First issue - map not found

Fix: put the files inside the desktop folder of the project, not inside assets.

Using `Gdx.files.internal("map.tmx").file().getAbsolutePath();` you can print the location you need to use.

Second issue - GL30 error

`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader: Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors: ERROR: error(#272) Implicit version number 110 not supported by GL3 forward compatible context ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors. No code generated`

Fix: copy the default shader and add `#version 330` as the first string to be written. The default shader can be found through the error printed in the console, you'll se GDX by default uses a very old version.

This is how my default shader looks like:

`static public ShaderProgram createDefaultShader () {
           String vertexShader = "#version 330 core\n"
              + "in vec4 " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
              + "in vec4 " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
              + "in vec2 " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
              + "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" //
              + "out vec4 v_color;\n" //
              + "out vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
              + "\n" //
              + "void main()\n" //
              + "{\n" //
              + "   v_color = " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
              + "   v_color.a = v_color.a * (255.0/254.0);\n" //
              + "   v_texCoords = " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
              + "   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
              + "}\n";
           String fragmentShader = "#version 330 core\n"
              + "#ifdef GL_ES\n" //
              + "#define LOWP lowp\n" //
              + "precision mediump float;\n" //
              + "#else\n" //
              + "#define LOWP \n" //
              + "#endif\n" //
              + "in LOWP vec4 v_color;\n" //
              + "in vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
              + "out vec4 fragColor;\n" //
              + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" //
              + "void main()\n"//
              + "{\n" //
              + "  fragColor = v_color * texture(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" //
              + "}";
           ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
           if (shader.isCompiled() == false) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error compiling shader: " + shader.getLog());
           return shader;
        }`

You'll then need to feed it to a Batch object which you'll then use to render the map:

`Batch = new SpriteBatch(1000, createDefaultShader()); // not required to be a spriteBatch
IsometricTiledMapRenderer renderer= new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map,spriteBatch);`

Third issue - black/blinking screen

Fix: make sure you've put `super.render();` inside the method `public void render ()`

Otherwise the screen will be black and if you render inside the `show()` method, you'll obtain a blinking screen.

**Hope this helps somebody!**

Comment: I've always had good luck putting all of the assets in the Android/Assets folder and then accessing them like this: `new Texture("filename.jpg"). Just make sure that once you put the assets in that folder, you Refresh All with gradle.

Comment: I have unchecked the android version thus the assets folder is inside core, i don't know if that changes how it works... Also, i've tried f5'ing the projects but nothing changed. Not a big deal tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

The cause is clearly "File not found".
It looks for it in `...\desktop\map.tmx` but you said it is situated in `assets/maps/map.tmx` I think you should acces it like:
`map = new TmxMapLoader().load(Gdx.files.internal("maps/map.tmx"));` 
That should do it. Let me know if it worked

Comment: "The method load(String) in the type TmxMapLoader is not applicable for the arguments (FileHandle)"  I've also tried to put the required files inside the desktop folder but it changed nothing.  *edit* I've changed it to "Gdx.files.internal("maps/map.tmx").file().getAbsolutePath();" and it returns "E:\Documenti\eclipseiso\desktop\map.tmx".

Comment: Got it working with: `Gdx.files.internal("map.tmx").file().getAbsolutePath();`, however now i get this error: `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader: Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: error(#272) Implicit version number 110 not supported by GL3 forward compatible context
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
` Which is quite strange as i never touched any GL3 configs.

Comment: The error is caused when i try to instantiate the IsometricTiledMapRenderer. In another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737426/libgdx-application-crashes-when-call-tiledmaprenderer-render) the issue were the indexes of the tileset, however i just tried with a map downloaded from a tutorial and it doesn't work either, plus i'm using separate images...That's weird.

Comment: I am glad your first question got solved. About the second one, I don't really know now, that looks pretty weird.

Comment: I've copied the default shader and added "#version 330" in front of everything, made a method that'd return the shader and istantiated a spriteBatch with it. Then, i've fed the batch to the renderer as its second argument. Now the project will launch but the screen will remain black.  sob.